# How to reactivate GRUB

Tags: grub2

Have a computer with two Ubuntu versions on it in separate partitions. For the fun of it, I installed WINXP Home in a thrird partition. I then deleted WINXP but now I don't get the GRUB boot menu. Is there a way to get the GRUB boot menu back without reinstalling one of the UBUNTU versions already on the hard drive?

Comment: For me, the easiest way always was Boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I agree. I've used Boot Repair on several occasions and it's worked perfectly. It involves booting from a LiveCD/USB, adding a PPA, and then install BootRepair. It provides a simple GUI and it should automatically detect your partitions and OSs. It then should ReInstall Grub2 and properly configure it for your OSs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed Vitor's suggestion and it worked. I now have the GRUB display again.

Answer (score 0):

Boot repair is one method, but the easiest method for me has always been:

1. Boot into an Ubuntu live cd.
2. Open up a terminal and do:

   `fdisk -l`

to find which partition your ubuntu is installed in (This is the same partition that's shown from your working ubuntu, `/dev/sdaX`. Once you know which, do

```
mkdir /mount/disk
mount /dev/sdaX /mount/disk

grub-install --root-directory=/mount/disk
```

and then restart your computer. You're all good to go.